# How to create HTML only if condition is true

Tags: javascript, php, html

I wrote this code:

```
<div class="col-md-4" id="message_widget">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    Latest messages
                    <?php
                    $query = $database->getConnection()->prepare('SELECT count(id) FROM messages WHERE messageRead = 0 AND messageTrash = 0 AND userId = ?');
                    $query->bind_param('i', $id);
                    if($database->getData($query)[0] > 0){
                        $messageNumber = $database->getData($query)[0];
                        echo "<span class='badge badge-danger badge-pill pull-right'>$messageNumber</span>";
                    }
                    ?>

                </div>
                <div class="card-block">
                    <table class='table' id="table">
                        <?php

                        $messageStatement = $database->getConnection()->prepare("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE userId=? AND messageDeleted = 0 AND messageTrash = 0 AND messageRead= 0 ORDER BY time_added LIMIT 3");

                        $messageStatement->bind_param('i', $id );

                        $latestMessages= $database->getDataAsArray($messageStatement);

                        if(!$latestMessages){
                            echo "<tr><td colspan='2' style='text-align: center'>No new unread messages</td> </tr>";
                        }
                        foreach($latestMessages as $message){
                            $time_added = $message['time_added'];
                            $number = $message['id'];
                            $subject = $message['subject'];
                            echo "<tr>
                                  <td><a href='showMessage.php?id=$number'>$subject</a></td>
                                  <td>$time_added</td>
                                  </tr>";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I only want to the page to build this col-md-6 if a certain condition is true. In every other case it should not be build. JavaScript is not an option this gives a weird effect I don't want (builds the page then add or removes the item)

I know that when the code is only HTML I can easily echo the code through php if a condition is true, but how can I create aboves code when a condition is true?

Comment: If you wrote that code you should be able to answer your own question. I think you need to try harder.

Comment: `if (certainCondition) { doSomething() }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this using `<?php if(): ?>---<?php endif; ?>`
it's called **the Alternative syntaxe** [see this](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

```html
<?php if(condition == true): ?>
<div class="col-md-4" id="message_widget">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    Latest messages
                    <?php
                    $query = $database->getConnection()->prepare('SELECT count(id) FROM messages WHERE messageRead = 0 AND messageTrash = 0 AND userId = ?');
                    $query->bind_param('i', $id);
                    if($database->getData($query)[0] > 0){
                        $messageNumber = $database->getData($query)[0];
                        echo "<span class='badge badge-danger badge-pill pull-right'>$messageNumber</span>";
                    }
                    ?>

                </div>
                <div class="card-block">
                    <table class='table' id="table">
                        <?php

                        $messageStatement = $database->getConnection()->prepare("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE userId=? AND messageDeleted = 0 AND messageTrash = 0 AND messageRead= 0 ORDER BY time_added LIMIT 3");

                        $messageStatement->bind_param('i', $id );

                        $latestMessages= $database->getDataAsArray($messageStatement);

                        if(!$latestMessages){
                            echo "<tr><td colspan='2' style='text-align: center'>No new unread messages</td> </tr>";
                        }
                        foreach($latestMessages as $message){
                            $time_added = $message['time_added'];
                            $number = $message['id'];
                            $subject = $message['subject'];
                            echo "<tr>
                                  <td><a href='showMessage.php?id=$number'>$subject</a></td>
                                  <td>$time_added</td>
                                  </tr>";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```